# Qt 5 can't lauch https adresses

Tags: c++, https, qt5, qtwebengine

I'm using `qtwebengine` from  **Qt 5.8.0** on my linux machine and i want to develop a web browser . i read the examples on my version and i successed to launch it using  `http` on localhost but when i set a `https` on `localhost` i get a blank webpage i tried :

> bool WebPage::certificateError(const QWebEngineCertificateError
>   &error)

But i don't know how to use it , and i get this error :

> [12988:13003:0428/122259:ERROR:cert_verify_proc_nss.cc(942)]
>   CERT_PKIXVerifyCert for localhost failed err=-8179

and i want to ignore certificate error

sorry i'm noobs in Qt ! 
anyone can help me please

Comment: This error caused by new (invalid ?!) libnss3.so binary. 
I had same problem with Chrome and I changed libnss3.so library from /usr/lib/firefox/libnss3.so (Chrome read from this path) with old version (firefox 51).

Answer (score 0):

You need to override this method. One way to do it is inherit from QWebEnginePage.

```
class WebEnginePage : public QWebEnginePage {
protected:
    bool certificateError(const QWebEngineCertificateError&) override {
        // Ignore certificate error
        return true;
    }
public:
    using QWebEnginePage::QWebEnginePage;
};
```

And then set page of the view

```
myView->setPage(new WebEnginePage(myView));
```